# How to interpret f(|x|) given f(x)=-x

Tags: functions

I just wanna double check that if only the $x$ variable is in the absolute value sign, (like $f(|x|)$), then if we have function $f(x)=-x$, $f(|x|)$ will be $-|x|$ rather than $|-x|$ right? Thanks a lot.

Comment: $f(|x|)=-|x|\leq0$ is correct.

Comment: @S.M.Roch Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right: we have $f(|x|)=-|x|.$